# Quota extension of Youtube Data Api

Tags: python-3.x, api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way to increase the quota limit of Youtube Data API which is 10000/day? or is there any other way to use Youtube Data API without any limitation of quota?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Google developer console. Under library where you have selected the YOutube api  Click manage

[image]

Click quota on the left

[image]

Then click the link to go to the quota page and request additional quota. Expect a wait. It took me between three to six months to get a quota extension.

There is no way to use the API without quota.